# C++ template class operator overloading with the same signatures

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

A simple C++ OO question regrading templates and operator overloading: In the following class, I have overloaded the index operator twice:

```
template<class A, class B>
class test
{
  A a1;
  B a2;
public:
  A& operator[](const B&);
  B& operator[](const A&);
};
```

Now, if I instantiate an object of this template class with the same typenames:

```
test<int, int> obj;
```

calling the index operator will result in an error, because the two overloaded functions will have the same signatures.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Sorry, if this is a basic question. I am still learning!

Comment: You could use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and only enable second overload if the types `A` and `B` are not the same

Comment: I think this is more of a design/analysis/requirements problem, and that you need to step back to the drawing board to avoid such problems. Yes you can do "hacks" to mitigate or work around the problem in the code itself, but such work-arounds tends to be less optimal and make the code much harder to understand and (more importantly) maintain.

Comment: Which would be `typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same_v<A, B>, B>::type operator[](const A&);` IIRC.

Comment: When indexing, how will you differentiate between the two overloads? i.e what should `test[5]` call? The first or the second indexing function?

Comment: You didn't provide context, but like Some programmer dude hints at... you probably need two aptly named functions, not operator overloads.

Comment: This is an [x y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Why not just make it an answer at that point?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox This is what I wanted to do: Lets's say that the class has two member arrays of the same size(A* a1,  B* a2), I wanted to have two index operators that take an element of one array and returns the corresponding element of the other array (map)

Comment: @MaxLanghof because as other said, there are some murky points, it solves OP direct question, but I'm not sure it's the proper answer for the actual problem. And seeing the last comment, it wouldn't have solved it apparently.

Comment: If you don't want to straight up forbid the `A == B` case, then you need a different way to distinguish between "give me the corresponding A/B". A named function (`getCorrespondingA(const B& b)`) would totally do the job - is there some requirement to use `operator[]`?

Comment: @MaxLanghof yes, I was asked to do it using operator[]. Thanks

Comment: So can you clarify how `myTest[1]` should behave? Should it give the value from `A` or `B`? Or is it maybe ok to forbid the `A == B` case?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a partial specialization:

```
template<class A>
class test<A, A>
{
  A a1, a2;
public:
  A& operator[](const A&);
};
```

Comment: This is technically a way, but you'd probably have to duplicate everything else that the class does. Still gets an up from me.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Usually code duplicate can be avoided by inheriting a common base.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid this issue and make the code more robust and expressive by converting the index to some other type that clarifies what the user wants. Usage would be like this:

```
bidirectional_map<int, int> myTest;
int& valueFor1 = myTest[Key{1}];
int& key1 = myTest[Value{valueFor1}];
```

Implemented like this:

```
template<class TKey>
struct Key { const TKey& key; };

template<class TValue>
struct Value { const TValue& value; };

// Deduction guides (C++17), or use helper functions.
template<class TValue>
Value(const TValue&) -> Value<TValue>;
template<class TKey>
Key(const TKey&) -> Key<TKey>;

template<class TKey, class TValue>
class bidirectional_map
{
  TKey a1;   // Probably arrays
  TValue a2; // or so?
public:
  TValue & operator[](Key<TKey> keyTag) { const TKey & key = keyTag.key; /* ... */ }
  TKey & operator[](Value<TValue> valueTag) { const TValue& value = valueTag.value; /* ... */ }
};
```

Now, `Key` and `Value` are popular names so having them "taken up" by these auxiliary functions is not the best. Also, this is all just a pretty theoretical exercise, because member functions are of course a much better fit for this task:

```
template<class TKey, class TValue>
class bidirectional_map
{
  TKey a1;   // Probably arrays
  TValue a2; // or so?
public:
  TValue& getValueForKey(const TKey& key) { /* ... */ }
  TKey& getKeyForValue(const TValue& value) { /* ... */ }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++2a, you might use `requires` to "discard" the function in some case:

```
template<class A, class B>
class test
{
    A a1;
    B a2;
public:
    A& operator[](const B&);
    B& operator[](const A&) requires (!std::is_same<A, B>::value);
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3bd40637361ca25)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example solution using `if constexpr` that requires C++17:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

template <class A, class B> 
class test
{
  A a1_;
  B b1_;

public:

    template<typename T> 
    T& operator[](const T& t)
    {
        constexpr bool AequalsB = std::is_same<A,B>(); 
        constexpr bool TequalsA = std::is_same<T,A>();

        if constexpr (AequalsB)
        {
            if constexpr (TequalsA) 
                return a1_;  // Can also be b1_, same types;

            static_assert(TequalsA, "If A=B, then T=A=B, otherwise type T is not available.");
        }

        if constexpr (! AequalsB)
        {
            constexpr bool TequalsB = std::is_same<T,B>();

            if constexpr (TequalsA)
                return a1_; 

            if constexpr (TequalsB)
                return b1_; 

            static_assert((TequalsA || TequalsB), "If A!=B, then T=A || T=B, otherwise type T is not available.");
        }
    }

};

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;  
    double y = 3.14; 
    string s = "whatever"; 

    test<int, int> o; 
    o[x]; 
    //o[y]; // Fails, as expected.
    //o[s]; // Fails, as expected

    test<double, int> t; 
    t[x]; 
    t[y]; 
    //t[s]; // Fails, as expected.

    return 0; 

};
```

Comment: Notice that OP returns the other type. Using `decltype(auto)` would fix that.

Comment: @Jarod42: I don't understand your comment, you mean `decltype(auto)` on the return type of the member function template? Why is this necessary, won't the `constexpr` parts together with the template argument deduction make sure the right `T` is replaced in the return (`T&`)?

Comment: Your code works, but in OP's case, it is not `T& operator[](const T& t)` but "`TRes& operator[](const T& t)`" (with `TRes = std::conditional_t<std::is_same<A, T>::value, B, A>`).  So even use traits for return type, or let compiler decide.

Comment: Hm, OK... OP is using `A& operator[](const B&); B& operator[](const A&);` directly. My code decides on `A&` or `B&` first using ADL, then the compiler enters the function body and used `if constexpr` to pick the return variable. OP asked about returning either `A` or `B` for different types, and in my code he/she can decide what to return if `A==B`. I still don't see the need for `decltype(auto)` in the return, as all cases are covered.

Comment: Firstly, there is no ADL here. Secondly, OP's code allows `test<std::string, int> t; std::string s = t[42];`, whereas your code expects `int i = t[42];`.

Comment: Moreover, you loose conversion: `test<std::string, int> t; t["c-string"];` is invalid for you (need `t[std::string("c-string")]`).

Comment: Both issues can be fixed, `decltype(auto)` for the first (and fixing implementation to return OP value ;-) ), and second is more tricky, but `std::is_same` and `std::is_convertible` might do the job but not sure it would give "better" code than alternatives.

Comment: Already on it, thanks. I'll update the answer anyway, if nothing, it can be an example for `if constexpr` I guess.